# How can you pass a parameter into you fitnesse test with soapui?

Tags: selenium, soapui, fitnesse

I am using soapui to run a fitnesse test page, send a request to jms queue and then again run a fitnesse test page:

1. In soapui execute Http test step http://HostRunningFitnesse.com:8000/TestPage?responder=test&format=xml
2. In soapui send request to jms queue
3. In soapui execute http test step to http://HostRunningFitnesse.com:8000/TestPageNumberTwo?responder=test&format=xml

Step 1 needs a specific unique number for testing that is created by fitnessse when the test page is executed from soapui but now when step 3 is executed it needs the same unique number created in step 1.

I was thinking to insert a random number into the test page from fitnesse with soapui and so keep the random number in scope of soapui but I don't know how. I thought of passing an extra parameter through the url like so localhost:8000/TestPage?responder=test&format=xml&**RANDOMNR=2317391** but was not able to retrieve this parameter in the fitnesse test page.

Somebody any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have to use SOAPUI to invoke the page?  Seems like you are using a really big tool to invoke a smaller one.

Answer (score 3):

There is no functionality in FitNesse for passing arguments to a Wiki page when you invoke it via the URL.  This has been asked about a couple of times in various forums, but so far no one has contributed a solution for it.

I would consider creating a fixture that can fetch your humber in some way. Have some cenralized thing that asks for the number to use when running the test and then pass that into your later steps in the test using symbols. http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.ImportantConcepts.FixtureSymbols

It's sort of clunky, but it could work.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate I believe. See *key=value* introduced on this page: http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices

Comment: You are correct. That should work. I haven't done it yet myself.

Answer (score 2):

`localhost:8000/TestPage?responder=test&format=xml&RANDOMNR=2317391`

I have just tested this using new 20150824 FitNesse jar, this works just fine. And on the page, you should refer the value using `${variable}` syntax. By calling the url this way `RANDOMNR=2317391` becomes a normal markup variable value assignment (same as `!define`). Documentation of this feature and other restful related features can be found [here](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices) as well. Search for "*key=value*"

Comment: This works and the other nice thing is you can still use the !define as a default value if applicable and the queryParam in the URL will override it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the random number from step 1 in the response? Is yes then you can use xpath to get the random value and use that value in step 3.

Would you be able to provide the response from step 1?

Comment: Yes I return the random nr in the response so it will be vailable for step 2 to use for the jms request in soapui. This is great but now in step 3 I need to pass the random nr to the fitnesse test page.... How to do this?